# Why it is not trivial that $Z_k$-flow gives $k$-flow

Tags: graph-theory, network-flow

In Diestel graph theory book, theorem 6.3.3 (Tutte 1950) states:

A multigraph admits a $k$-flow iff it admits a $\mathbb{Z}_k$-flow.

I don't understand why do we need a proof, because, by definition, a $k$-flow is a flow all of whose values are between $1$ and $k$, and these are exactly the values we have in $\mathbb{Z}_k$ ... it looks to me that we called the set $\{1,2,\ldots,k-1\}$ by two names, say $A$ and $B$, and we claim that we have a flow with values from $A$ iff we have values from $B$....

What do I miss here?

Comment: Not actually fluent in this topic, but I'll guess that a $k$-flow means a $\mathbb{Z}$-flow with values in $\{0\dots k-1\}$ considered as integers, while a $\mathbb{Z}_k$-flow is a flow, whose values are $\{0\dots k-1\}$ considered as integers *modulo $k$*. So, the algebraic structure (presumably, addition) must be used used somehow. Also, in $\mathbb{Z}_k$ there is no notion of ordering compatible with addition, while in $\mathbb{Z}$ there is.

Comment: This makes sense, thanks!